# How to minify Angular 8 Dev Build

Tags: angular, build, compression, webpack-4

By default Angular CLI (ver-8) does not remove the comments and minify js dev build generated files. (main.js,vendor.js,scripts.js etc).

We are importing JitCompiler so need Dev Build with optimized generated output files(vendor.js, main.js ect)

I have added my own webpack file webpackext.config.js. and using it through "@angular-builders/custom-webpack:browser. I am able to remove comments from generated files  using below configuration. I need to also minify generated files using some plugin. How can we do that, need information about plugins and configuration method as well.

```
const UglifyJsPlugin = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
  entry: './src/main.js',
  output: {
    filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist')
  },
  plugins: [
    new UglifyJsPlugin({
      uglifyOptions: {
     
        output: {
          comments: false
        }

      }
    })
  ]
}
```

**Why we need this**: We are loading lazy loaded module using Require JS. Lazy loaded module(sample.module.js) is placed by end user.  They generates lazy loaded module from their application. As importing jit compiler to our system to create end user's  component on demand so we can not go with production build . We have upgraded our system from angular 4 to angular 8.  Earlier on Angular 4,  all the js files are minified. But in Angular 8, js file's size are increased to double.

```
    require.ensure(
          ["assets/samples/sample.module.js"], 
          (require) => {
            let SampleCo = require(assets/samples/sample.module.js");
            this._compiler
              .compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync(
                SampleCo.SampleCustomModule
              ).then((compiled) => {
                const component1 = compiled.componentFactories.find(
                  (m) => m.selector == "sample-comp1"
                );    });
              //here we create component with ViewContainerRefr
          },
          "custom/sampleLib" 
}
```

After using UglifyJsPlugin, generated js files are minified. However getting error while loading system, error as below

```
Uncaught Error: Can't resolve all parameters for hC: (?).
    at Li (vendor.js:1)
    at n_._getDependenciesMetadata (vendor.js:1)
    at n_._getTypeMetadata (vendor.js:1)
    at n_.getNgModuleMetadata (vendor.js:1)
    at n_.getNgModuleSummary (vendor.js:1)
    at vendor.js:1
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at n_.getNgModuleMetadata (vendor.js:1)
    at n_.getNgModuleSummary (vendor.js:1)
    at vendor.js:1
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it now by adding this to the `configurations` section in the `angular.json` file:

```
"configurations": {
            "dev": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "2mb",
                  "maximumError": "5mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb",
                  "maximumError": "10kb"
                }
              ]
            }
}
```

then running: `ng build -c=dev`

Answer (score -2):

Why do you need to uglify the dev build?  The dev build should never go anywhere except your dev box.

All QA/prod releases should be prod builds which are automatically tree-shaken and uglified.

As such, you want your debugging code to not be uglified so that the sources tab in the browser tools is readable.

Comment: Our page is opening very slow on DEV. We don't have a Deployment on PROD yet and it will take some time until we are on PROD. So we want to test on DEV, if the reason for slow opening is that the files are not minified. Isn't that a valid reason to want it minified on DEV?

Comment: performance in the dev environment should not be expected to be production-level.  A non-minified and non-tree-shaken build is (by definition) not optimized code so won't run as if it were.  If you're concerned about the speed, do a prod build and do your performance testing again that output.